# VTD-XML how to handle one-many relationship with in xpath

Tags: vtd-xml

Facing an issue while using VTD-XML to parse the xml using large xpath
which has,

1) one - many relationship with xml elements with in a single xpath
for example,

```
<group>       
<element>
  <model>
    <product>BMW
      <feature>
      </feature>
    </product>
  </model>

   <model>
      <product>FORD
         <feature>
      </feature>

      </product>
  </model> 

  <model>
  </model> 

</element>
<groups>
```

issue is, am using multiple autoPilots to break the one-many relationship. howver the underlying naigator is same. some times i am not getting all the elements.

Comment: Have you tried to duplicate vtd navigators?i.e. creating new instances by calling clone or dup?

Comment: our XSD size is very big. so creating a new vtd navigator for each 1-2-many relationship will be very costly.
i think VTD could be very useful if it could use some kind of mapping file to convert to a POJO, similar to jiBx.